# SQLite row IDs do not match the ListView row IDs

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite database and a `ListView` displaying in the main activity.  In the `ListView`, I display the details of each list number and upon pressing the list item, a new activity opens up which displays the details in a `TextView`.

I have a delete function for each of these `ListView`s and they are not working properly. Essentially, a unique ID is given to each created `ListView`, which is how the SQLite databases should work. However, upon deleting a row within the `ListView`, the unique ID increases but the row ID deletes that number and moves everything up.  This means that after you delete an item, the row IDs and the database IDs no longer match up and when trying to select an item within the `ListView`, it crashes. This is an extract from my database adapter class:

```
 public Integer deleteStat(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(STATS_TABLE, "id = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
}
```

This is my first attempt in the main activity. I got some information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869551/sqlite-row-ids-not-matching-listview-android) post but a failed to get the correct integer and received syntax errors:

```
obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

 TextView pos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
 displayText(Integer.parseInt(pos.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
}

public void displayText(int pos)
{
    pos++;
    String s = "";
    s += pos;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayStatsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", s);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

This is my second attempt in the main activity. I used [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) tutorial to help me. The code I used from that website ruined the entire delete functionality:

```
 obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
           int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;
           int id_To_Search = arg0.getCount() - arg2;

           Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayStatsActivity.class);

           intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
           startActivity(intent);
```

How do I get the database IDs to match up with the row IDs? Any suggestions on how to do that?

**EDIT: Added in Hashmap Code. When I press on a ListView Item, nothing happens**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mydb = new StatisticsDbAdapter(this);
    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllStats();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

    obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    /*
     New code starts here
    */
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");

        if (Value > 0) {
            //means this is the view part not the add contact part
            Cursor cursor = mydb.getData(Value);
            hashMap.put(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(0));

 obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
     TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
                    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                    dataBundle.putInt("id", hashMap.get(textView.getText().toString()));

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayStatsActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
 }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SQLite Row IDs do not match ListView` This is quite obvious. Imagine your ids begin with 953 (because you made a lot of trials and deleted all the test records a lot of times). Do you pretend that your ListView starts from item number 953? NO, obviously not. It will start populating its items at ITS item number 0.

Comment: So how do I go about making sure that the Database ID stays in line with the Row ID after deleting rows from the listview when I try to click on them to call them back?

Comment: Google keywords: `android listview database delete`

Answer (score 0):

You should never pass a `ListView` position to delete a row in a database. I have done that many times before. First of all, within the class you are managing the click events, create a new `HashMap`. This `HashMap` will be used to store our row IDs from the database and we'll refer to that rather than the `ListView` item position. To create it, type this code:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Once you have done that, in the function where you display all of the rows in the `ListView`, you must also load up the same items into the `HashMap` like this:

```
hashMap.put(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(0));
```

Please note that `cursor.getString(1)` might not be what you used. Please replace the 1 with your appropriate column number that has the name stored within it. `cursor.getInt(0)` gets the row ID from the database and the column number might be different for you, too. Now, within our `OnClickListener` function, we can type:

```
obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view) {
       TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putInt("id", hashMap.get(textView.getText().toString()));

       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayStatsActivity.class);

       intent.putExtras(bundle);
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

Please note that the `hashMap` variable needs to be within the same class where you manage the click events of your ListView or you will get mistakes. Some of the parametres that you originally passed were removed since you don't need them. Also, I found this to work much better using a `RecyclerView` but that's now up to you. If you're having problems, please don't hesitate to comment below and I'll try to answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much for this great response!

I've attempted to add a couple of things, and the hashMap appears to be working.

However, when I go to click on some of the items that I am adding currently, nothing is happening now.


I believe it may have something to do with the line
`TextView pos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTitle);`

Do you think that I shouldn't be calling the title line here? I'm unsure what variable I should be referencing in my TextView when I believe that line is just to grab the ID that the data should be coming from.

Let me knwo what you think!

Comment: It probably is that line that you mentioned. What I recommend is that you visit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208827/how-to-extract-the-text-from-the-selected-item-on-the-listview) link and get the selected items TextView value and pass that instead.

Comment: Please check the code I provided you again. I have tweaked a few things that should now work.

Comment: If you think the code and tips I provided you has helped, please press the green tick to accept this as an answer.

Comment: I have never seen the line `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view)` written that way before. When I try to type it like that (without the argument for int arg2, long arg3) it is not happy with the syntax. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It actually appears to be an issue with how I am initializing my Hashmap. Can you take a look at this entire section that I have added above and let me know if something looks strange?

Comment: Hello Jake. I apologise for not helping you for so long. I have had some account problems. You are initialising the `hashMap` correctly. I'm not too sure on what could be the problem since I don't use the `ListView`. Could you email me your project so I can have a look at it properly since I can't tell you too much from all of the code you have provided me. I will email you back and post another answer indicating the changes I have made.